# Is contourplot a good choice to show simultaneous conditions for different functions?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

I have three functions

```
f1[u_,t_]:=1/32 (7 + 4 Cos[2 t] + Cos[4 t] + 2 Cos[t (-3 + u)] + 
2 Cos[2 t (-1 + u)] + 12 Cos[t] Cos[t u] + 2 Cos[2 t (1 + u)] + 
2 Cos[t (3 + u)]);
f2[u_,t_]:= 1/32 (7 + 4 Cos[2 t] + Cos[4 t] - 2 Cos[t (-3 + u)] + 
2 Cos[2 t (-1 + u)] - 12 Cos[t] Cos[t u] + 2 Cos[2 t (1 + u)] - 
2 Cos[t (3 + u)]);
f3[u_,t_]:=1/32 (5 - Cos[4 t] - 4 Cos[2 t u] + 4 Sin[2 t] - 2 Sin[2 t (1  + u)] - 2 Sin[2 t - 2 t u])
```

I have used

```
specificTimes = 
ContourPlot[{f1[u,t] == 0.9999, 
f2[u,t] == 0.00001, f3[u,t] == 0.00001}, {u, 0.0, 
4}, {t, 0, 8 \[Pi]},

ContourStyle -> {Blue, Black, Red}, Frame -> True,

FrameTicks -> {{{0, \[Pi]/2, \[Pi], (3 \[Pi])/2, 2 \[Pi], (5 \[Pi])/
   2, 3 \[Pi], (7 \[Pi])/2, 4 \[Pi], (9 \[Pi])/2, 5 \[Pi], (11 \[Pi])/2,  6 \[Pi], (13 \[Pi])/2, 7 \[Pi], (15 \[Pi])/2, 8 \[Pi]}, {None}}, {{0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 
  2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0}, {None}}}]
```

to obtain the point **simultaneously**, `f1` be as much as possible near to 1.0 and `f2` and `f3` be as much as possible near to 0.0.

But in the contourplot there are some points which do not show simultaneously the above condition. How can I show the points in the [t, u] surface that satisfy the condition?

Comment: You have a typo:  `f3[[u,t]] == 0.00001` should be `f3[u,t] == 0.00001`.

Comment: I suspect the "missing" points will become more apparent by using `ContourStyle -> {Green, Black, Red}` and moving farther away from 0 and 1: `f1[u,t]==0.95, f2[u,t]==0.001, f3[u,t]==0.001`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ContourPlot[(f1[u, t] - 1)^2 + f2[u, t]^2 + f3[u, t]^2 , {u, 0, 
  4}, {t, 0, 8 Pi}, Contours -> {0.001, .01}, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> (Which[# < .001, Red, # < .01, Blue, True, None] &),
  PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Changing the color scheme slightly, adding in `PlotPoints -> 200`, and moving a bit away from 0 and 1 might do what you need:

```
specificTimes = ContourPlot[{f1[u, t] == 0.95, f2[u, t] == 0.001, f3[u, t] == 0.001},
  {u, 0.0, 4}, {t, 0, 8 \[Pi]}, ContourStyle -> {Green, Black, Red},
  ImageSize -> Large, PlotPoints -> 200, Frame -> True,
  FrameTicks -> {{{0, \[Pi]/2, \[Pi], (3 \[Pi])/2, 
      2 \[Pi], (5 \[Pi])/2, 3 \[Pi], (7 \[Pi])/2, 4 \[Pi], (9 \[Pi])/2,
      5 \[Pi], (11 \[Pi])/2, 6 \[Pi], (13 \[Pi])/2, 
      7 \[Pi], (15 \[Pi])/2, 8 \[Pi]}, {None}},
    {{0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0}, {None}}},
  PlotLegends -> {"f1", "f2", "f3"}]
```

[image: Contour plot]

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your answer. But I wish to not have any red points without being overlapped by green and black points. The red points are the places that just one function is 0.001.

Comment: On the other hand, 0.95 is large. for this reason the black places are as ellipsoid.

Comment: In fact, I do not have any point by itself (lonely points). I wish to find overlapped points.

Comment: Not exactly.  The "red points" are contours that many times look like points because of their small area.  But if you only want to see where all three functions are true (when all are zero or 1), then something else would need to be done.  Where all three colors show is approximately where all three equations are satisfied.

Comment: Yes, Please see just a red point. It satisfies for example `f2[u, t] == 0.001` but it does not satisfy `f1[u, t] ==0.95`. The center of each elliptical shapes is the points that I am trying to show them. JUST them and not other unimportant points.

Comment: But I wish remove any `just red point` or any `green only` point. I wish to keep just overlapped points.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe contour plots isn't what you want but producing the individual contour plots is a good start for knowing your functions.  It doesn't appear that too many (if any) of the points in the area of interest have values of `u` and `t` that satisfy `f1[u,t]==1` and `f2[u,t]==0` and `f3[u,t]==0`.

So maybe what you need is to set a threshold of closeness to 1 and 0 and just evaluate the functions on a fine grid of points.  Here is one approach with two different thresholds:

```
α = 0.01
n = 250;
t = Flatten[Table[If[f1[u, t] > 1 - α && f2[u, t] < α && f3[u, t] < α,
     {u, t}, {0, 0}], {u, 0, 4, 4/n}, {t, 0, 8 π, 8 π/n}], 1];
ListPlot[t, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{0, π/2, π, (3 π)/2, 2 π, (5 π)/2, 3 π,
     (7 π)/2, 4 π, (9 π)/2, 5 π, (11 π)/2, 
     6 π, (13 π)/2, 7 π, (15 π)/2, 8 π}, {None}},
   {{0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0}, {None}}}, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: Threshold = 0.01]

```
α = 0.0001
n = 250;
t = Flatten[Table[If[f1[u, t] > 1 - α && f2[u, t] < α && f3[u, t] < α,
     {u, t}, {0, 0}], {u, 0, 4, 4/n}, {t, 0, 8 π, 8 π/n}], 1];
ListPlot[t, Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {{{0, π/2, π, (3 π)/2, 2 π, (5 π)/2, 3 π,
     (7 π)/2, 4 π, (9 π)/2, 5 π, (11 π)/2, 
     6 π, (13 π)/2, 7 π, (15 π)/2, 8 π}, {None}},
   {{0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0}, {None}}}, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: Threshold 0.0001]